# Unable to upload a image in Karate Framework using graphQl mutation

Tags: graphql, karate, web-api-testing

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clovd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6FQ.png)](ht[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJMru.png)tps://i.stack.imgur.com/06hOp.png)

Unable to upload an image using graphQl query in Karate framework.

ERROR:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: no step-definition method match found for: multipart logo logo = {read: 'data/hummingbirdbird.jpeg', filename: 'hummingbirdbird.jpeg', contentType: 'image/jpeg'}
classpath:superdeker/createteam/createTeam.feature:15

Can someone help me here pls.

Comment: since you are new here, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for next time

Answer (score 0):

It should be `* multipart file logo = {}`